# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController with UITabBarController is not showing correctly in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application in which UITabBarController as a rootViewController with two controllers. One is an empty controller and the second one is Picker controller extends from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. The problem is view is going behind the tab bar and due to that view is cutting off from the bottom. I just highlighted the area in the screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` doesn't support subclassing: [link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/)

```
Subclassing Notes
The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class does not support subclassing.
```

However, the problem is that the view of your ABPeoplePickerNavigationController subclass is extending under the tab bar.
You can, for example, change it's size at runtime in this way

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGRect rect = self.view.bounds;
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height - 40;
    self.view.frame = rect;
}
```

Note, the 40 is only an example, you should calculate the height of your tab bar controller because it can change for other screen dimensions and rotations.

Or, better, you can search for the underlying UITableView instance and set the `contentInset` property.

**EDIT**
This seems to have problems with the status bar, since the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is unable to extend the navigation bar under the status bar if you change it's frame

In both this cases, however, your app will probably be rejected, because you are subclassing a class that explicitly forbids it.

A better and "legal" way to add it is to use a container view controller

Look at [This Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz6labxdtwcr5kk/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Containment.zip?dl=0)

Create a new view controller, add a container view, then add the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` in this way:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController instance
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *controller = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    // add a new child view controller to self
    [self addChildViewController:controller];

    // alert the child that it has been added to the father
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // update the child view frame to fit into the containerView
    controller.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;

    // translate autoresizing mask into constraints, this is not needed but I usually do because is more pratical
    [controller.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    // add the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` view to the container
    [self.containerView addSubview:controller.view];

}
```

Even in this way `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` has problems with the status bar (it doesn't extends correctly under it), so I constrained the container view to the Top Layout Guide and changed the color of the main view of `ContainerViewController` to fit with the color of the navigation bar

Comment: have you tried in `viewDidAppear` ? in `viewWillAppear` it doesn't work. I tried in xcode before answering

Comment: here a link to a test project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/47hswos0xznj2kk/testpicker.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let me check and will let you know

Comment: I tried your code but now the navigation bar is cutting from the top.

Comment: Added a screenshot in the post

Comment: This seems to be related to a problem with the underlying UINavigationController (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController). It seems to not extend the Navigation Bar correctly when subclassed. I suggest you to change approach and use UINavigationController Containment. Now I add an example to my answer

Comment: Basically I am not using storyboard and in my case while creating a tabbarcontroller I am adding navigation controllers and then while tap on contacts tab I am creating ABNavigationController and insert into the tabbarcontroller. So how can I able to solve the above mentioned problem in this case.

Comment: I do not believe (from experience) that Apple have any kind of automatic scanning for "illegal" subclassing. They do for APIs, but that's not the same.

Comment: Laombax solution does not work with CNContactPickerViewController instead of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Answer (score 1):

In **viewWillAppear**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.topViewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
}
```

In **viewDidAppear**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    CGRect tabBarFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;        
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, statusBarFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, CGRectGetMinY(tabBarFrame) - statusBarFrame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's my answer to the problem or at least some additional input for you to work out a complete solution.

The problem to me seems to be that because `UIPeoplePickerNavigationController` is not subclass-able or at least is not recommended to be by Apple, you can't use it entirely anyway you like.  What I mean is `UIPeoplePickerNavigationController` is meant to be used as a modal view, which should be presented full screen on iOS and on top of every other view controller.  You shouldn't try to use it as a push view controller on a navigation controller stack.

So my suggestion is quite straight-forward.  You should simply use your `UITabBarController` as the receiver of the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method.  That will take care of presenting the modal on top of the tab bar.

You can access the `UITabBarController` through the `tabBarController` property of your current view controller:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePickerController = [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController new];
[peoplePickerController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:peoplePickerController animated:YES completion:^{}]
```

Note: I'm writing this from memory so there may be some method naming mistakes.